# How to measure similarity between tag distributions?

Tags: correlation, similarities

I have a table of movie tag assignments where each row is (userId, tagId, movieId). I'm using test data set from Movielens with a million rows.

**I want a function that given two films returns a similarity score** (I do want to be able to find e.g. the 10 most similar films given a query film, but I want to understand how the comparison/scoring function works first and figure out how to optimise doing that at scale as a second step, if that makes sense?)

I can easily get, e.g. the distinct tags for a film, or the 'tag distribution' for a film (i.e. a list that is tag name, and percentage of people who tagged this film who gave it this tag), or perhaps do some clever weighting if I care about some tags being more/less important.

The part I can't quite get my head around is how to compare two half-overlapping sets of data in order to score them., i.e. given any two sets/distributions of tags for two movies, I don't know how to say how any two are 'near' or 'far' from each other.

My goal is to be able to write python code to do this and to at least understand what it's doing if not necessarily understanding a whole implementation in a library, etc. If it makes more sense to compile the whole dataset rather than write the function to find the 'distance' between two movies that's ok too.

Comment: So we are comparing two discrete distributions? E.g., film 1, (rom-com 20%, action 70%, drama 10%) versus film 2 (rom-com 0%, action 90%, drama 10%)? and we want a measure of similarity of those percentages for the two films?

Comment: @innisfree Yes. Except the labels are user generated tags so there are a lot of them and many are very 'sparse'. Comparing two similar films you may have 50% tag overlap. Comparing two different films you may have 5% or 0% tag overlap. Also the tag percentages could be done in a way that they sum to 100% (i.e. each tag measured as a %age of total tags for this film), or not if each tag measured as percentage of users who applied this tag (out of those two tagged this film).

Comment: hmm, well it seems there are 2 problems. The one in my first comment, and now a second one: unify tags that refer to the same thing, i.e., `rom-com` = `romantic comedy` == `romntc comdy` (typos), etc

Comment: @innisfree I guess I'm not too worried about those problems right now, but rather more interested in the problem of if I have two data sets of frequency distributions of any-things, how do I measure how similar they are? e.g. how similar is (a:5, b:3, c:2) to (b:1, c:4, d:5, e:1) or (c:3, f:4). Those data sets can be convered into things that sum to 100% or not, depending on if that's required / useful